# Background Image on Webpage

Tags: html, image, jsp, web, netbeans

I am working to develop a small web app with netbeans 8.2. The background image is not shown on the web page by using css property. But when i copy and paste the same code in head elements the image shows.

'''

```
<style>
            body {
                background-image: url('assets/images/back.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
```

'''
and the css file have
'''

```
body{
    background-image: url('assets/images/back.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
} '''
```

while i have a css file link in my head element
'''

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Optional Bootstrap Theme -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/Mycss1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>//this is css file having body code'''
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When the CSS is in your `<head>` section the routing is correct.

When you copy into a different directory `"assets/css/Mycss1.css"` the background picture url is incorrect.

you will need to make sure the url of your background picture is referencing the correct picture. Try utilizing "`../assets/images/back.png`" I cant see your file structure but something similar will work.

This will get you on the right track.